# is it possible to extract the specific data in a JSON data , without reading all the values

Tags: json

I have this JSON Data .
My question is that , is it possible to extract the specific data in a JSON data , without reading  all the values .
I mean is it possible to query the data as we do in SQL ??

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("4e61501e6a73bc73f82f91f3"), "created_at" : "2011-09-02 17:52:30.285", "cust_id" : "sdtest", "moduleName" : "balances", "responses" : [
            {
                    "questionNum" : "1",
                    "answer" : "Hard",
                    "comments" : "is that you john wayne?"
            },
            {
                    "questionNum" : "2",
                    "answer" : "Somewhat",
                    "comments" : "ARg!"
            },
            {
                    "questionNum" : "3",
                    "answer" : "",
                    "comments" : "Yes"
            }
    ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to write extra code to do it, or use a third party library.  There are a few available: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=json+linq+sql

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you use an [incremental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incremental-json) JSON parser, you'll have to parse the whole JSON first. After that, it depends on your programming language's abilities of how you can filter. For example, in Python

```
import json
obj = json.loads(jsonData)
answeredQuestions = filter(lambda response: response.answer, obj["responses"])
```